# Partial sum of Negative Binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Excersice: find the probability of having $k$ successes before $r$ failures in a Bernoulli process with success probability $p$.

If I'm not mistaken this is calculated with a Negative Binomial distribution. What I should find is

$$\sum_{j=k}^{k+r-1}\binom{j-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{k-j}$$

I've tried changing variables like

$$p^k\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\binom{k+j-1}{k-1}(1-p)^j$$

but I can't find a way to improve this, and couldn't find anything in this site that solves it.

Comment: Why do you have a sum then? If you know you have $k$ successes and $r$ failures and the last one is a failure, should it not be just $\binom{k+r-1}{k}p^k(1-p)^r$?

Comment: Since it's before $r$ failures, I understand that the case that the first $k$ are success is valid, and so is all the cases in the middle

Comment: rb.gy/s2hjwp ---- Your series is the expansion of a hypergeometric function + some other stuff. So I don't think theres a trivial closed form, unless you're fine with hypergeometric functions.